# Why does Ubuntu's webkit inspector look (and work) just like Safari?

Tags: python, debugging, webkit, pygi, midori

In older Ubuntu, the python-webkit inspector looked like Chrome, as you can see in these screenshots: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132459 (It had some annoying bugs, too.) I see Midori's inspector also looks just like Safari, and [still has some bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/midori/+bug/1328358).

[image]

In the latest 14.04's python-webkit embedded browser (and also Midori browser), the inspector actually looks just like [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) - and also seems to still have bugs (icons missing, problems selecting, etc.). Is there a reason for this drastic change, or is it just a default configuration?

Is there a recommended way to get the webkit-inspector fully working?

*Update*

I filed a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/midori/+bug/1328358). The big problem with this is when you make a highly Webkit-integrated project using [Python-GTK-Webkit](http://theravingrick.blogspot.com/2012/04/making-gtkwebkit-inspector-and-enable.html) such as in [this example](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~rick-rickspencer3/+junk/webkit-dev-tools-sample/view/head:/webkit-dev-tools-sample.py). Debugging within the webview is problematic.

**Update**

I noticed the other day that Midori actually freezes up completely, in the same case that Safari does, where no other browser freezes. So it seems there's more than just how the inspector looks, they must have taken the code from the Safari-webkit branch... but why?

It should be noted that Midori on Windows has an inspector like Chrome, not Safari, so it seems to be a bug in Ubuntu's GTK-Webkit.

Comment: It could be the change from Webkit1 to Webkit2, both can be used in 14.04 which could explain the difference in behaviour.

Comment: @Timo How so? Both Midori and Python's embedded webkit show the Safari inspector, and seem to have the same bugs.